# Node.Js server by socket.io, crashes and stop work after one day

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, crash

my Node.Js server work fine but After a day on their own to stop!
please help me. 
I run a server with the following command:

```
$forever start index.js
```

and my index code is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var https = require('https');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('key.txt', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('Certificate.txt', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer); // web socket external module
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error('uncaughtException', err.stack);
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.get('/newpost', function (req, res) {
    res.end(new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, '  ').replace(/\..+/, ' ') + ' users : ' + Object.keys(io.of("/").adapter.nsp.connected).length);
});
app.post('/newpost', function (req, res) {
    res.end();
    io.emit('newdata', req.body);
});
httpsServer.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and client javascript code is:

```
var socket = io('https://www.example.com:3000');
socket.on('newdata', function (newPost) {
    console.log(newPost);
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    var td1 = '<td class="pforumtitle"><a href="' + newPost.pbburl + '/forumdisplay.php?' + newPost.pforumid + '"><div>' + newPost.pforumtitle + '</div></a></td>';
    var td2 = '<td class="ptime"><a href=""><div>' + newPost.ptime + '</div></a></td>';
    tr.html(td1 + td2)
    $('#list').prepend(tr);
    $('#list tr:last').remove();
});
```

forever logfile:

https://www.irantk.ir/mylog.txt

Comment: Humm ... maybe share your server logs ?
It's hard to see something wrong here.

Comment: thank you. Where node.js server logs are stored? I uploaded for you.

Comment: run `forever list`, it will answer your question ;)

Comment: could be an hardware issue

Comment: my log file: https://www.irantk.ir/mylog.txt. Hardware is healthy.

Comment: @SteevePitis Are you've check my log files? My key.txt and certificate.txt in the same directory with index.js. please help me.

Comment: How do you execute your code ? `forever ...` ?

Comment: @SteevePitis Like this: 'forever start index.js' . Why not find key.txt file in log?

Comment: dunno, try like this : `fs.readFileSync('./key.txt', 'utf8');`

Comment: @SteevePitis ok I changed like this `fs.readFileSync('./key.txt', 'utf8')` and `fs.readFileSync('./Certificate.txt', 'utf8')`. For this reason forever was Stoped?

Comment: Yes, now node is able to find your credentials ?

Comment: @SteevePitis When stopped forever after one day, I saw through the log files key.txt not find. Now that is running, how can see?

Comment: Just look your log.
Or you can just run your script with node and see your console (`node index.js`)

Comment: @SteevePitis until forever not stop, in log and console only show : `listening on *:3000` :|

Comment: So everything is ok ;)

Comment: @SteevePitis Thankful. Before the change today was the same. that's mean Before the stop forever, there was nothing in the log.
If not stop tomorrow I will let you know.

Comment: @SteevePitis after one day stoped and log: `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './key.txt' ` :(

Comment: That's weird xD ! If node can't find the file, it's supposed to crash instant not one day after load ... what says your console when you run `node index.js` ?

Comment: @SteevePitis only show : `listening on *:3000 `. Please see the screenshot: [screen shot of console](https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/02/23/2017-02-2313_09_59-irantkStandard.zocevaluationmode.png)

Comment: try to create a post and see what happens in your console

Comment: @SteevePitis I change key.txt code for show error, Like this: `var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('key.txt', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
    console.log(contents);
});` but when start There is no error. after one day stoped whith error!! in consol when send post only show : `listening on *:3000`

Comment: @SteevePitis I've added this code : `console.log(req);` and my consol log: [console-log.txt](http://www.todaymagazine.ir/console-log.txt).

Comment: @SteevePitis, Is this the case of the crash ?: There is a limit on the number of connections the server can create, but that should be more than enough

Comment: There is no crash ! Everything works well. If your server shutdown, your problem is not here ... Check your connection etc ...

Comment: @SteevePitis My server not be shutdown And everything works well, except socket.io file :(

Comment: @SteevePitis Yesterday I run the server with the following command:
`node index.js` And the terminal until today, did not close. Today server, as well as active.
This indicates that the problem is in the `forever`. What is your idea?

Comment: Try with `pm2` which is in my opinion better than `forever` : http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: @SteevePitis whith pm2 my problem sloved and After a day did not stop.. thank you. Over time, exponentially greater amount of RAM used.Is this normal? After 48 hours, one GB RAM is consumed. At first, only a few Meg was used.

Comment: @nekooee : no it's not normal. I haven't that much RAM consumed by my pm2. take a look here: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1314 but I couldn't help you for this issue.